# Importance of the Cup Product in Topology?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

On p. 15 of Fenn's *Techniques of Geometric Topology*, it says:

> In many ways, the cup product [for cohomology] is the 'soul' inside all topological existence theorems. Statements like: two lines in the projective plane meet; a real continuous function takes all intervening values; and so on, are all manifestations of the cup product.

Is this true? Does anyone know of any reference discussing either these particular examples or similar ones further?

I know how to prove both using much more elementary means, but it is unclear to me how either could be construed as a manifestation of the cup product, and I am even more at a loss to identify by myself other examples besides the two mentioned of manifestations of the cup product (in elementary topological existence theorems). I would like to be able to do so in order to gain more intuition about the cup product.

Comment: The cup product is Poincare dual to the intersection pairing on submanifolds, so if you want to see if manifolds in two homology classes necessarily intersect, you take their Poincare duals, take their cup product, then Poincare dualize back to see the homology class of the intersection.

Comment: If you want references, you could do worse than reading Bredon's book and the section on intersection theory and Poincare duality

Comment: @ThomasRot You are right, I just read it, and answers a lot of my questions -- even the example with the projective plane is addressed specifically! Thank you for the suggestion!